# How to know the order of functions to be executed in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, order-of-execution

For example, I was told that WHERE will be executed before GROUP BY, and HAVING will be afterwards, so the lines of code should be written in that order.
How could I know or from where should I read to know in which order are all functions in PostgreSQL (or other kind of SQL for that matter) to be written and executed?

Comment: What you mention `where`, `group by`, `having` are, along with others the basic components of SQL (in any rdbms). You can the nominal order from the documentation for [select](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html).

Answer (score 0):

The logical order of evaluation of the different parts of a `SELECT` statement are dictated by the SQL standard. You should learn that from any good book on the subject.

Note, however, that the actual execution can differ. For example, a `WHERE` condition can be executed *before* the `FROM` clause is completed, even though the logical order is the other way around. Such transformations are fine as long as they don't change the query result.

To see the order in which operations are executed in an individual query, look at the *execution plan* of the query, which can be obtained with the `EXPLAIN` command in PostgreSQL.